# While loop act twice JS

Tags: javascript

I used this code:

```
var list = was_talkWindows.querySelectorAll('.msg:not(.was_added)');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    list[i].className += cssClass;

    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'was_addButton');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        was_button_act(this.parentElement);
    });
    btn.innerHTML = buttonName;
    list[i].appendChild(btn);
}
```

however, friend told me that *.msg:not(.was_added)* is too slow, so doing it in the opposite way:

```
var cssClass   = ' was_added';
var buttonName = 'start waiting';

if (was_set_standby_auto == true)
{
    cssClass  += ' was_standby';
    buttonName = 'cancel';
}

try {
    var currectMSG = was_talkWindows.querySelector('.msg:last-child');

    while (currectMSG.classList.contains('was_added') == false)
    {
        currectMSG.className += cssClass;

        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btn.setAttribute('class', 'was_addButton');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            was_button_act(this.parentElement);
        });
        btn.innerHTML = buttonName;
        currectMSG.appendChild(btn);

        currectMSG = currectMSG.previousElementSibling;
    }
} catch (err) {}
```

but the code add the button twice each time for the last one.

not really understand this behavor.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but if you're going to use `[0]` to get just the first match of the selector, you can just use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: If your original code is working as you want, I think you should just stick with it. Unless you have hundreds of `.msg` elements, the performance of `:not(.was_added)` is probably not going to make a noticeable difference.

Comment: as the time pass the server create more and more `.msg`. it's why i'm trying other way. (in the first way it's happened fewer times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a site that is not under your control, it does not always know what is running, and it took me a long time to realize that the problem is not adding buttons twice (against logic), but anyone who does not I edit the code at the same time.

so declare just once:

```
var was_msgList = was_talkWindows.getElementsByClassName('msg');
```

and the loop (every 2 seconds):

```
for ( var i=was_msgList.length; i-- && was_msgList[i].getAttribute('data-status') == null; )
{
    was_load_addButton(was_msgList[i],attStatus,buttonText);
}
```

any ideas for change are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `previousElementSibling` instead of `previousSibling`, so that it skips over text nodes.

And add the `was_added` class to the element so it won't be processed again later.

```js
var was_talkWindows = document;
var cssClass = " newclass";
var buttonName = "Click me";

try {
  var currectMSG = was_talkWindows.querySelectorAll('.msg:last-child')[0];

  while (currectMSG.classList.contains('was_added') == false) {
    currectMSG.className += cssClass;
    currectMSG.classList.add('was_added');

    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'was_addButton');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      was_button_act(this.parentElement);
    });
    btn.innerHTML = buttonName;
    currectMSG.appendChild(btn);

    currectMSG = currectMSG.previousElementSibling;
  }
} catch (err) {}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="msg was_added">Text</li>
  <li class="msg was_added">Text</li>
  <li class="msg">Text</li>
  <li class="msg">Text</li>
  <li class="msg">Text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: the code run in loops. so it's still happened twice

Comment: What's supposed to prevent it from happening twice? The loop looks for elements that don't have the `was_added` class. Maybe you should add that class to `currectMSG` so it doesn't repeat it.

Comment: Is `was_added` supposed to be in `cssClass`? Your original code didn't show what that is.

Comment: You should also use `.classList.add()` rather than concatenating to `.className`.

Comment: 1. any idea for make the code better is bless.  2. change the main question with more information